# save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user' with Foreign Keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer

I am trying to POST a new User in User table and assign attribute to this user in the next related table UserAttribute. UserAttribute table contains 'user' field, which is foreign key to the User table.

> User.id = UserAttribute.user

My POST method creates a new record in User table, hovewer I can not create relation in UserAttribute table. I am getting:
save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'.

It is strange because the User is successfully created in User table.

I tried to save record in two ways. You can find the code on belove.

What is more, I tried transactions too.

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=180)
    roles = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    firebase_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    progress_sub_step = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    step_available_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    progress_step = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    last_login_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'


class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'attribute'


class UserAttribute(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'attribute')
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_attribute'
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserAttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAttribute
        fields = ('attribute',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attribute = UserAttributeSerializer(many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'name', 'firebase_id', 'attribute')


    @transaction.atomic()
    def create(self, validated_data):
        attributes = validated_data["attribute"]
        del validated_data["attribute"]
        
        firebase_id_v = validated_data.get('firebase_id')
        user_save = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        # Second method
        # user_save = User(**validated_data)
        # user_save.save()
        for attribute in attributes:
            a = UserAttribute.objects.create(user = user_save, **attribute)
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
class UserAttViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserAttribute.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserAttributeSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: it is giving an error because the `attribute` object is not saved.

Comment: Do you mean  attribute as a field from UserAttribute? Or do you mean Attribute model?

Comment: An instance of the `Attribute` model is not saved when trying to save the `UserAttribute` instance. Since it requires the `atttribute` field to be a `ForeignKey` and hence the error, probably.